# RSelenium can not connect to firefox and chrome profiles

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I run this for chrome:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)
```

or this for firefox:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = c('firefox'))
```

and I receive receptively this errors:
for chrome:

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4567/wd/hub.
  Please ensure a Selenium server is running.
In addition: Warning message:
In rsDriver(verbose = FALSE) : Could not determine server status.
```

for firefox:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4567/wd/hub.
  Please ensure a Selenium server is running.
In addition: Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = c("firefox")) : Could not determine server status.
```

I tried to find a workaround so I used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42253022) post:

```
library(wdman)
> selServ <- wdman::selenium(verbose = FALSE)
> selServ$log()
$stderr
[1] "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\\Users\\iris\\AppData\\Local\\binman\\binman_seleniumserver\\generic\\3.3.1/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar"

$stdout
character(0)

> selServ <- wdman::selenium(retcommand = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
> cat(selServ)
C:\PROGRA~3\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\iris\AppData\Local\binman\binman_chromedriver\win32\2.28/chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Users\iris\AppData\Local\binman\binman_geckodriver\win64\0.15.0/geckodriver.exe" -Dphantomjs.binary.path="C:\Users\iris\AppData\Local\binman\binman_phantomjs\windows\2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe" -jar "C:\Users\iris\AppData\Local\binman\binman_seleniumserver\generic\3.3.1/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar" -port 4567
```

and when I try again to use the command for Chrome I receive the same error

```
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4567/wd/hub.
  Please ensure a Selenium server is running.
In addition: Warning message:
In rsDriver(verbose = FALSE) : Could not determine server status.
```

Is there any workaround for this issue or anything I made wrong in the previous steps?

Comment: Give said scraping a try with [`splashr`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr)?

Comment: I had a corrupt jar file (check its size), too. Deleted it, let wdman re-download it, then it worked. Another problem I had was an outdated java.exe, which I replaced.